# CodeIgniter Setup Question

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to get this URL to work on a codeigniter installation, just installed the newest version today (2.0.2):

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/accounts

So I have set my default controller in routes.php to test.php, and inside my controller, test.php I have this code:

```
class test extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('test');
}

public function accounts() {
    $this->load->view('accounts');
}
}
```

and then I have a test.php and an accounts.php inside my views, it loads the test.php view when I go to http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/

But when I go to http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/accounts it gives me a 404. I have been reading the Getting Started and it says "By default CodeIgniter uses a segment-based approach", and then gives an example similar to what I'm doing. But then I read a little further it says: "By default, the index.php file will be included in your URL" . So I added this into my htaccess file (located at mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I made sure that the module is loading inside httpd.conf. It still doesn't go to my accounts.php view. I have also tried:

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/index.php/accounts

But another 404, what am I doing wrong? Any advice would help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default controller is what loads when there are no url segments present - that's it.

If you want `/accounts` to load the `test` controller and `accounts` method, you'll have to use a [route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) like this:

```
$route['accounts'] = 'test/accounts';
```

Otherwise you'll have to have an accounts controller or access it through `/test/accounts/`

Comment: I think I understand now, I have setup a 2nd controller which loads the accounts view. http://mydomain/pete/ci_test/index.php/accounts now loads the account view, I would like to get rid of the index.php, but I can work with this for now, thank you!

Comment: FYI Pete, leading upper or all lowercase class names will not break your code, but as mentioned - its best to stick to the suggested naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should be uppercase for the class name:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
```

And as far as accessing it, the url should be:

***Edit*** Fixed the subfolder now that I noticed

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/test/accounts

or

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/index.php/test/accounts

Comment: @Pete They should unless your codeigniter install is not in `/pete/`. Also `CI_Controller` looks like an older version. What version are you using? The latest extends `Controller` instead.

Comment: He said he was on 2.0.2, which indeed uses `CI_Controller` instead of the old `Controller`. His install directory is `pete/ci_test`, and upper/lowercase should not make any difference - it's more of a style guideline.

Comment: @Wesley okay see it now. I also said "should" as more of a recommendation versus "need to" as in do it or I'll throw many small pillows at you. Okay I thought his folder was `/pete/` and not `/pete/ci_test`. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I went into the same problem, so i've looked around. You should use this .htaccess content. It worked for me.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

onteria_ is correct that your controller should be uppercase. This is not a requirement, but rather a "best practice."

However, I think the naming of your controller vs. the name of the subfolder is throwing people off. It looks like you have your installation inside a folder called `ci_test`. In that case, to access it, the URL should be either

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/test/accounts

or

http://mydomain.com/pete/ci_test/index.php/test/accounts

Comment: Controller upper or lower case should not make a difference. At least it doesn't for me, and as far as I know PHP is not case sensitive about class or function naming... WHy would his default controller work if lowercase was the problem?

Comment: I should have worded that better - it is a "best practice" rather than a requirement. Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear to OP (and any other folks who might come across this) that this was not his problem, that's all. Especially since 2/4 answers originally suggested that controller name casing was the potential issue.